# Is there a symbol that represents the value of the row or column and can be used in defining functions?

Tags: excel

I am dealing with an incredibly large stack of data (close to a 1000 rows). I want to write a function for all of the cells in a column that takes the value from one cell in each row, divides it by the value from another cell in the same row, and writes the result on a third cell in the same row. In other words, as to row X, it takes AX, divides it by BX, and writes it on CX; and as to row Y, it takes the value in AY, divides it by BY, and writes on CY.

As I said, I am dealing with a large stack of data and I really would like to be able to write one function for the entire column, rather than having to write one function for each cell in the column. Conceptually, it is clear to me that I need some way of using the row number as the variable in defining the function and apply that to the entire column. I do not know how to bring that to application though.

Comment: +1 @pnuts - it's a basic feature of Excel to automatically adjust a formula as you fill it down.

Comment: @pnuts and Tim Williams: Thanks guys. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pnuts is absolutly correct, however, if you really want to do this with VBA try this:

```
Sub LoopRange()
  Dim rCell As Range
  Dim rRng As Range
  Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A1000")

  For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    Range("C" & rCell.Row).Formula = "=A" & rCell.Row & "/B" & rCell.Row
  Next rCell
End Sub
```

Make sure your range is right otherwise you'll get a divide by zero error.

Comment: Thanks. @pnuts and Tim Williams's solution was easier. But yours also worked and gave me a first lesson in using VBA in excel.